# Having trouble creating an onclick button event

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I am trying to create a very simple webpage with a button that runs this script in js. I have a js file and an html file.

```css
//var button = document.querySelector("button")

//button.onclick = function() {
demo = function() {
    const CambDict = require("camb-dict");
    const dictionary = new CambDict.Dictionary();
    let lexicon = ["Flâneur", "Shibboleth", "Farrow", "Bon viveur/vivant"]
    let randLexicon = lexicon[Math.floor(Math.random() * lexicon.length)]
    console.log(randLexicon)

    dictionary.meaning(randLexicon)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dictionary</title>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <h1>Simple Dictionary</h1>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">New word</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script src="dictionary.js"> function myFunction() </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction () {
    const CambDict = require("camb-dict");
    const dictionary = new CambDict.Dictionary();
 let lexicon = ["Flâneur", "Shibboleth", "Farrow", "Bon viveur/vivant"]
    let randLexicon = lexicon[Math.floor(Math.random() * lexicon.length)]
    console.log(randLexicon)

    dictionary.meaning(randLexicon)
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dictionary</title>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <h1>Simple Dictionary</h1>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">New word</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you be more specific? what error are you getting?

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 23,
  "colno": 22
}

Comment: okay the reason is that require is not defined.

Comment: Right... how to fix?

Comment: you have to run your code in Node.js and have camb-dict installed.

Comment: Not it says myfunction isn't defined

Answer (score 0):

Do not add additional scripts inside script tags with a src.

> The SCRIPT element places a script within a document. This element may appear any number of times in the HEAD or BODY of an HTML document.
>
> The script may be defined within the contents of the SCRIPT element or
> in an external file. If the src attribute is not set, user agents must
> interpret the contents of the element as the script. If the src has a
> URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve
> the script via the URI.

Do this instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dictionary</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Simple Dictionary</h1>
  <button id="demo-button">New word</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script src="dictionary.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    var button = document.getElementById("demo-button");
    button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

    function myFunction() {
      console.log("button was clicked");
      // const CambDict = require("camb-dict");
      // const dictionary = new CambDict.Dictionary();
      // let lexicon = ["Flâneur", "Shibboleth", "Farrow", "Bon viveur/vivant"]
      // let randLexicon = lexicon[Math.floor(Math.random() * lexicon.length)]
      // console.log(randLexicon)

      // dictionary.meaning(randLexicon)
      // .then(console.log)
      // .catch(console.error)
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It just says "button was clicked" in the console developer menu but no output? How to get output to display (full disclosure: am noob).

Comment: Can you also include your dictionary.js file? I commented out the function's logic because it won't work. I don't have the script for your dictionary

Comment: Just grabbed it from here: https://openbase.com/js/camb-dict/documenta